# Can't work out rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup a rewrite rules(s) that will:

- redirect anything but /path and files to another site
- then if path is /path/*, rewrite the url to index.php

Here is my rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path.*
    RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|css|jpg|png|jpeg) http://www.domain.com [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

For some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Other than making sure that you have mod_rewrite turned on, you need to change your first condition to also check for `index.php`, because after the second rule, the process loops and you end up getting redirected to domain.com:

Change:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path.*
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(path|index.php)
```